# How can I insert a QR scanner into my android app?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've tried many times to embed a QR code scanner into an activity on my app, but I've only found solutions that need to install an external library (ZXing).
Can you help me?

Comment: what is your problem actually??

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner).You get the solution for you question.Small suggestion, when you ask question explain clear and Show what you done.

Comment: ...yes? You're going to have to install an external library to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solution for your problem . Actually there is a class is missing from zxing library . If  you want I can give you working Zxing lib + my sample app .

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Thank you really.

Comment: just download lib from link

Comment: This is sample project . Just import it in eclipse and enjoy . And one more thing dont forget to endorse me . :)